# how do I check for duplets in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sorted array and I want to create a new element for every unique object,

How can I check if this has the same value as the previous one? 
this is were I am right now-

```
        var element =""
        $.each(tableContent, function(){
            alert(element +','+this)
            if(this != element){
                console.log('ingen ny')
                element = this
            }
            else{
                console.log('ny')
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean duplicates?

Comment: if you want to get unique elements of array then check this http://www.codeplussoft.com/Snippets/javascript-unique-elemets

Comment: What's inside `tableContent`?

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq may help

Answer (score 0):

you can check this example:

```
  var arr=[1,2,3,5,5,6,7],prevEl='',newArr=[];

$.each(arr, function(index,item){
  console.log(prevEl);
  if(prevEl != item){
    newArr.push(item);
  }
  prevEl = item;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take idea from this code, the alert message displays the unique values only..

```
 function myFunction() { 
      var arr=[1,2,3,5,5,7,7];
      var current, previous;
      previous= arr[0];
      for(i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
      current= arr[i];
      if(current!=previous)
      alert(previous);
       previous= current;
   }
   alert(current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array quite easily, since it's sorted:

```
tableContent.filter(function(elt, idx, arr) { return elt !== arr[idx-1]; });
```

In other words, filter out all elements equal to the previous value.